# how to use pandas.concat insted of append

Tags: pandas

I have to  import my excel files and combine them into one file.
I used below code and it's worked, but I got information "The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead"

I tried to use concat but it doest't work please help.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import glob
all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob(r'path\*.xlsx'):
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
    all_data = all_data.append(df,ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension instead loop with `DataFrame.append`:

```
all_data = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f) for f in glob.glob(r'path\*.xlsx')],
                     ignore_index=True)
```